# How can I execute a JS function before ng-init is called in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-init` directive defined on my `html` tag, with it initializing some data. I want a certain JS function to run before this initialization occurs. How can I accomplish this? Basically my objective is to assign the data returned by this function to the variable initialized in `ng-init`.

Comment: So why use `ng-init` at all? If you have a function that calculates the value of the variable, then why not simply assign the result of that function directly to a scope variable, in the controller itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150289/angularjs-running-initialization-code-when-view-is-loaded

Comment: @Stewie, you are right, your comment helped me solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is really bad approach but this should work.

1. Write your method in another script file and include it before you are putting ng-init.
2. Wrap it up as self executing function i.e.

   (function(){
           //Your code
       })();

If you want to get the results,  expose a global variable from the script file.