# AngularJS: How to initialize controller from $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

If I instantiate controller in html file I can initialize it using ng-init:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="init()">
```

How can I initialize controller specified in $routeProvider?

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/structDefinedKeyValue', {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/myTemplate.htm',
        controller: 'MyCtrl'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just to say, using `$stateProvider` from `'ui.router'` would make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150289/running-angularjs-initialization-code-when-view-is-loaded

Answer (score 0):

The router will instantiate the controller when loading the state. If you need some initialization work, you could call your `init` function inside the controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function () {

    // ...

    init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to call it from outside with a parameter,as I will have different instances of the same controller code. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Looks to me that you need state/route parameters. As you are using ngRoute, I guess you can have a look to [$routeProvider documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) and inject `$routeParams` in your controller.