# Where to Write Controller Initialization Logic

Tags: angularjs

When writing AngularJS controllers, I often wonder where it would be best-placed to write initialization logic.

For the sake of this illustration, let's assume that I've separated-out my initialization logic into a separate `init()` method.

As far as I can tell, I have three possible ways to invoke this as part of the controller start-up:

- *init in constructor* - As per proposed solutions to [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150289/running-angularjs-initialization-code-when-view-is-loaded), you **could** invoke `init()` from the constructor. Initialization-in-constructor is widely accepted as an anti-pattern in most languages. I'm particularly against this because I have use-cases where I have class inheritance, and wouldn't want the parent constructor to invoke `init()` (which may have been overridden in the child class) before the child constructor has finished executing.
- *ng-init* - Invoke `init()` by using a ng-init` directive in the view. This isn't great, as it's coupling my view to the internal workings of my controller.
- *delayed init from constructor* - Use the `$timeout` service to schedule the invocation of `init()` after a delay of *0 milliseconds*. This will allow the child constructor to be fully executed before invoking the initialization logic.

None of these solutions seems like an overly clean way of solving such a basic problem. Are there alternatives that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

If you keep thins simple:
one state and one controller per view, 
than it may make sense to use the [$stateChangeSuccess](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) event for your init stuff.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    // transition completed
    // let's init things
})
```