# How to force start controller when click on just opened link

Tags: angularjs, controller, route-provider

When i try to go to just opened link, `$routeProvider` doestn't start the `controller` again.

Example:

- in html code I have some links(dynamically), for example url1, url2, url3.
- when I click on url2, `$routeProvider` starts the controller.
- after some time, If I click again on this link - controller doesn't get started (only works for different links)

How to force start the `controller`, when clicked on just opened link? 
Or run init code for all links on click(but after this go to target link)?

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150289/running-angularjs-initialization-code-when-view-is-loaded , it looks that on every view load the controller indeed does get reloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$route.reload();`

From the Docs:

> ### `$route.reload();`
>
> Causes `$route` service to reload the current route even if [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) hasn't changed.
>
> As a result of that, [ngView](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) creates new scope and reinstantiates the controller.
>
> [-- AngularJS $route API Reference - reload](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#reload)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your example? Based on how you have configured your $stateProvider might be the problem.